# Tool for validating a deliverable?

Tags: validation, continuous-integration, inventory

I'm looking for a tool that validates deliverable (such as a .tgz, .war/.jar, .zip file) against a list or inventory of files that it should contain. Something that checks for every file that should be in the deliverable (per the list).

This is part of a final validation step in a continuous delivery cycle.

An OSS solution would be ideal. Have not found anything, but want to check before setting off and writing one.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you could do something like:

```
gzip -dc deliverable.tgz | tar --list > incoming.txt
diff incoming.txt expected.txt
```

You shouldn't have to write more than a couple lines of a shell script.